# Spatial transformation of volumes

Tags: xtk

I have 2 nifti image volumes that I would like to display together using XTK.  Both of them are already converted to NRRD using Mevislab's relevant ITK modules.  Both volumes were acquired in the same MR session, but they differ in spatial resolution and field of view (even by orientation), so it's important that XTK takes in mind the "space directions" and "space origin" fields of the NRRD to display them correctly in terms of relative spatial position.  This seems not to happen in practice though.

I already read a question and answer on fixing the "space origin" part, but it's still running into problems with the "space directions".  My latest attempts were trying to modify the transformation of the volumes after loading them, but this doesn't seems to have any effect on the displayed volumes.  I could however successfully do this with a TRK fiber file, but changing a volume's tranformation doesn't yield any effects.  So the question being: how do I correctly load a (NRRD) volume and while taking into account it's full spatial tranformation to patient/scanner space, so multiple loaded volumes get matched up correctly?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the scan orientation is not taken into account at the moment. This should happen soon so, since it is very important.

As a workaround, it is possible to transform each Slice of a volume using the transform methods. You basically loop through the children and then apply to each one the transform.

If you are willing to contribute the features to the parser, it would be great! Also, the NII format is now supported so you don't have to convert to (the much slower) NRRD.